# How can I use static const members in CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am currently porting my ray tracer to the GPU by using CUDA, and to get my feet wet I am modifying the example CUDA 6.5 project (adding an array of integers) to use a custom Color struct instead of integer. However, I am getting various errors whenever I compile my code.

I have all of my class's member functions declared with the `__host__` and `__device__` attributes, and I have all of the definition code in a `.cu` file. In my color struct, I have a `Darken` method that interpolates the given color to black by the given amount. I also have a static definition for black that the `Darken` function uses.

For example, here is a trimmed down version of the struct:

```
// **********************
//       .hpp file
// **********************

struct Color
{
    float R;
    float G;
    float B;

    __host__ __device__ static Color Darken(const Color& c, float amount);

    static Color Black;
};

// **********************
//        .cu file
// **********************

const Color Color::Black( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );

Color Color::Darken(const Color& c, float amount)
{
    return Color( Math::Lerp( c.R, Black.R, amount ),
                  Math::Lerp( c.G, Black.G, amount ),
                  Math::Lerp( c.B, Black.B, amount )  );
}
```

However, whenever I go to compile the code, I get the following error:

```
error : identifier "rex::Color::Black" is undefined in device code
```

I have tried adding `__device__`, `__host__`, `__global__`, and various combinations of those specifiers to the colors, but the CUDA compiler tells me that they are not applicable. Also, after I add any of the specifiers to the static colors, I get the same error for the color's `R`, `G`, and `B` components.

Does anyone know how I can use the static color definitions in CUDA?

Comment: Also (I know this is an unrelated question), if I use a local color for black it works but then I get the error `ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_ZNK3rex5ColorplERKS0_'`. I assume that means that CUDA can't find the default constructor for the color, but I have `__device__` and `__host__` specified for the constructors and destructor...

Comment: class static data members are [not supported](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#data-members) in CUDA C/C++.  You could create a `__constant__` variable prior to the class method definitions that would use that variable, and put the data there.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I was not aware. Thank you!

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I've taken the liberty of paraphrasing your comment into a community wiki entry. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: as always @talonmies, thanks for continuing to "curate"

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#data-members), the CUDA object model does not support static data members, so there is no direct way to do what you are trying to do.

As pointed out by Robert Crovella in comments, you could use a `__constant__` memory declaration to achieve similar functionality, and you can also use namespace tricks to get around duplicate definitions when using whole compilation, or use `extern` with a single definition in separate compilation.

[This answer was added as a community wiki entry to get this question off the unanswered question list]